# Call method associated with directive in linking function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have the following code:

```
   .directive('ticketingChat', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl:  '/Reply/ReplyScreen',
            scope: {},
            controller: "TicketController",
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {

                if (attr["ticketid"]) {
                    ctrl.loadTicketById(attr["ticketid"]);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I am trying to call the "loadTicketById" in my controller. However I can't seem to get an instance of the controller in the linking function whatever I do.

[image]

Other than that, the controller works in the directive.

Comment: What is the code of your controller ?

Comment: That fourth argument in the link function `ctrl` is passed when you `require` the controller for another directive. I've never seen anyone try to require the controller for the same directive, but you might try doing just that: `require: 'TicketController'`.  Just a guess :)

Comment: Based on the verbiage your code is using, it sounds like you actually want a ticketService, that you would use as a dependency of your directive.

Comment: Is `loadTicketById` added to the scope by any chance? Then it's not part of the controller.

Comment: Do you have a controller with that name loaded in the same module?

Comment: As @SunilD. said. You may assume that the directive requires its own controller by default, but it does not.